# Putting a box of text over a bunch of images

Tags: html, image, text, box

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAEIE.jpg)

I have been trying to figure out how this website managed to put a box with text in on-top of an image. Here is the link to the website: http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/Backgrounds_g162.html

How did they mange to put a box of text over these images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"></link>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <img src="image/image.jpg" />
                <div id="text">
                    <p>Test of Text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>


#html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#container{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}

#container img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

#text{
    width:100%;
    height: 30%;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top:-41%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

PATH-
  css
    style.css
  image
    image.jpg
  index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

The `div.box-text` has absolute positioning inside the same container that also contains the image and is pulled down by `bottom: 0`.

Here's a [demo and how-to](https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that:

1. Put a background image on div and then add a span which contains text.
2. Put an image and a span in div, but make the span's position absolute with `bottom: 0`.